# Multiplatform phone tracking

Tags: gratis, android, ios, gps, phone

I have an Android and iOS phone that I'd like to be able to track on-demand. I don't want a solution that drains the battery (if that makes sense). I was hoping for something where I can just open up an app or the browser, it send a message to the phone to report the location back. If I've understood correctly, its how "find my iphone" on iOS and "find my phone" on android work...its just the two aren't compatible with each other and I need to login to a browser on the computer to use "find my iPhone".

I just want to be able to see where a phone is - preferably from the other phone, but a computer will do also. I intend to use it when I need to locate the other phone, I don't need a history of where the phone has been.

Are there any solutions that are cross platform?

Comment: I've integrated your comments directly with the question. One point still remaining is whether a self-hosted solution (where the devices report to) is acceptable?

Comment: PS: Checking with [my list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_antimalware#group_448), the following apps seem to be available on both mobile platforms: [xfi Locator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funreality.software.nativefindmyiphone.lite), [Find My Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsp.android.phonetracker). There might be more. No idea how well they fit your other criteria, though.

Comment: @Izzy - Thanks! I was talking with someone in the pub, apparently you can do this with Google Maps & location sharing. I will give this a go first and try something on your list if not.